# Cooker hood lighting stops working with LED

Tags: light-fixture

I have recently tried to replace the light bulbs of my cooking hood for LED ones. They are G4 and the old ones were halogen. The thing is: the hood has 4 bulbs. I started replacing and testing with no problem until i reached the 4th. As soon as i replace the 4th (on any position, tried them all) it stops working and when i replace one of them (any place) back to an old halogen one, they all light up again. It seems this is like a low current limit of sort (since it was supposed to work with higher power halogen ones). Does anyone have any idea if it is and how to bypass it (other than having a 3 LED - 1 halogen setup :P? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Do you have a model number for the hood?

Comment: On any position is a dead giveaway that the light controller is not compatible with the LED’s.

Comment: OK, you just created two different accounts.  This site lets you post with a "cookie based" account that is not tied to any email/password (or Facebook or Google).... however, then, this weird stuff happens. Please go to the same browser you used the last time, and [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) and use that on all your devices.

Comment: After you do that, hit "Contact" (bottom of page, left edge) and ask them to merge your accounts into the one you registered.